# Check if inputs are empty or have text instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, input

as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/kztnmm9o/ I am trying to check if the inputs are empty. If they are empty I want to display the div id="fehler", if every input has a value (must be a number, if not it shall display id="fehler" as well) I want to do the function. I am pretty new to javascript, might be a obvious mistake.
Thank you for your help!

This is the orignal javascript code without checking the inputs, which works:

```
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll("#eing1, #eing2, #eing3");
    for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
        selectors[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
         if (event.keyCode == 13) {
         document.getElementById("button").click();
       }
        });
    }

  function ausgeben(){


            var kostentisch = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing1").value)
            var bruttogehalt = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing2").value)
            var arbeitstage = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing3").value)

            var stundenlohn = bruttogehalt/arbeitstage/8;
            var arbeitszeit = arbeitstage*8;
            var produktivitaetssteigerung = arbeitszeit*0.12;
            var produktivitaetssteigerung2 = arbeitstage/produktivitaetssteigerung;
            var gewinnprotag = produktivitaetssteigerung2*stundenlohn;
            var amortisationszeit = Math.round(kostentisch/ gewinnprotag);

            document.getElementById("arbeitszeit").innerHTML=arbeitszeit + " Stunden";
            document.getElementById("produktivitaetssteigerung").innerHTML=produktivitaetssteigerung + " Stunden";
            document.getElementById("amortisationszeit").innerHTML=amortisationszeit + " Tage";
    }
```

Comment: your 'if' statement is wrong. If you want if statements, they need to be inside the for loop

Comment: ah yes thank you!
But im struggling anyway. How should code look like to check if all inputs are filled with numbers and if not it should display an ID. If its filled all correctly I want to run a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kztnmm9o/3/

Changed the testing to this:

```
    var test = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
var error = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; ++i) {
    if (test[i].value == "")
  {
    test[i].style.borderColor = "red";
    error = true;
  }
}
```

I also made some minor changes following this logic, but it should be pretty simple to understand.

I also added `this.style.borderColor = "transparent";` to `keyup` event but I'm not sure whether you like or not. So change on will.

Comment: ah thats nearly the solution. Thank you! But I wanted it if there is any input empty, to do not display the 3 ids at the end but to display the id="fehler". If all inputs are filled than the the other way round: display the 3 ids at the end and do not display  the id "fehler"

Comment: Sorry, that last query was terrible, and did not do as I expected. I have updated the fiddle and the code. Hopefully this is what you want

Comment: thats pretty perfect! now I understand how to do it. Thank you very very much!